# How to change dock icons to match those from the Arc theme?

Tags: gnome, icons, themes

I have installed the [arc-theme](https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme) and [arc-icon-theme](https://github.com/horst3180/arc-icon-theme) and activated them in gnu-tweaks. My dock doesn't look the like the arc-theme images though, as shown here:
[image]

What I have instead looks like the dock is correct, but the actual icons on the dock don't match. I do have my folders looking like in the image, in my file browser.
[image]

I am using a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.1. How can I get my icons on my dock to match that in the first image?

Comment: It can be assumed that you have attempted to log-out and login back again, or even doing a restart? Normally, the dock should also immediately adapt the new icons (even without log out). Any special extensions installed? Try disabling them one by one to see if that removes the issue.

Comment: Indeed, I've restarted the device. I don't think I have any other extensions installed. I also tried to get this to work on a usb version of Ubuntu 20.04 with the same result. I use gnome-tweaks and gnome-shell-extensions to change the shell appearance in Tweaks